# Displaying Menu On Context Menu Extjs

Tags: extjs, grid, contextmenu, split-button

Up until 6.2, context menu on a grid worked fine by doing

```js
itemcontextmenu: function (a,b,c,d, e) { 
  contextmenu.showAt(e.getXY()); 
}
```

But with 6.5, the menu doesn't show at the given XY coordinate if the menu is shown outside of the context menu. I have included an example below. Anyone seen this issue? I have tried turning on the animation option too, but the menu doesn't constrain within the panel, so when you right click at the bottom of the grid, the menu shows at the bottom below the panel.

Any input is highly appreciated

**Working example**

1. Right click on any grid row
2. Context Menu shows where you clicked.

**Non-working example**

3. Click on the Menu Button (menu shows below the button)
4. Right click on any grid row
5. Context menu shows where it was displayed below Menu Button instead of where you clicked.

```js
var mymenu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
        items: [
            // these will render as dropdown menu items when the arrow is clicked:
            {text: 'Item 1', handler: function(){ alert("Item 1 clicked"); }},
            {text: 'Item 2', handler: function(){ alert("Item 2 clicked"); }}
        ]
    });
Ext.create('Ext.button.Split', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    text: 'Menu Button',
    menu: mymenu
});
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    fields:[ 'name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [
        { name: 'Lisa', email: 'lisa@simpsons.com', phone: '555-111-1224' },
        { name: 'Bart', email: 'bart@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1234' },
        { name: 'Homer', email: 'homer@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1244' },
        { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1254' }
    ]
});
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        scope: this,
        itemcontextmenu: function (a,b,c,d,e){
            e.stopEvent();
            mymenu.showAt(e.getXY());
        }
        
    }
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle in 6.2 and it has the exact same behaviour as 6.5

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/23kn

The issue is you are assigning the same menu for context menus to the split button.  You would need to destroy and recreate the menu each time.  Also as a side note you should cache the context menu on the grid otherwise every time you right-click you are creating a new menu and the old one still remains...big memory leak.

Answer (score -1):

You can prevent memory leak like this.

```
new Ext.grid.Panel({
    plugins: 'viewport',
    title: 'Users',
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'top',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'splitbutton',
            text: 'menu',
            menu: mymenu
        }]
    }],
    store: {
        data: [{
            name: 'Lisa',
            email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
            phone: '555-111-1224'
        }, {
            name: 'Bart',
            email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
            phone: '555-222-1234'
        }, {
            name: 'Homer',
            email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
            phone: '555-222-1244'
        }, {
            name: 'Marge',
            email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
            phone: '555-222-1254'
        }]
    },
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    listeners: {
        scope: this,
        itemcontextmenu: function (a, b, c, d, e) {
            e.stopEvent();
            var mymenu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
               items: [
                 {
                     text: 'Item 1',
                     handler: function () {
                         alert("Item 1 clicked");
                      }
                 }, {
                       text: 'Item 2',
                       handler: function () {
                           alert("Item 2 clicked");
                       }
                }
             ],
             listeners:{
                 hide:function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        mymenu.destroy();
                    },2000);
                }
             }
            });
            mymenu.showAt(e.getXY());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That's going to destroy the menu on the first show. What happens if the user wants to show the menu a second time?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli when menu hide after 2 second it destroy

Comment: Right, which means that it can't be used again.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli if you want to open this again then you need to place it inside itemcontextmenu function so that every time when you click it creates it again and on hide it destroyed.

Comment: The current iteration hasn't assigned mymenu by the time it's used on the button.